# Using inline source-maps breaks webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a library with src/ and lib/ and compiling with `babel —source-maps inline`. src -> lib. I use this library in another project (webpack+babel-loader).

When not inline, the source-maps aren’t available. It points to the files - `lib/a.js` instead of `src/a.js`. So you'd have to use inline source-maps

When source-maps are inline, babel generates `lib/a.js` correctly, but webpack build fails with the message - `Module build failed: Error: No element indexed by 1`

Comment: Can you share your webpack.config file?

Comment: I have the same issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1485